# google symbol is not showing on Mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using Mapkit in my code and  everything works fine. but  the google symbol which usually shows on google Map(Mapkit) is not showing any more. Can anyone suggest me what happen to my code any suggestion.

Thanks in advance...

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    } 
    else {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}




-(void)LoadLocationOfOffices {
    places = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Place *aPlace1 = [Place alloc];
    aPlace.title = @"xyz";
    aPlace.subtitle = @"xyz ";

    CLLocationCoordinate2D crd1;
    crd1.latitude = ;
    crd1.longitude = ;

    [aPlace1 addCoordinates:crd1];
    [places addObject:aPlace1];
    [aPlace1 release];
    aPlace1 = nil;

    /*
     Object having address of office 2
     */
    Place *aPlace2 = [Place alloc];
    aPlace2.title = @"xyz";
    aPlace2.subtitle = @"xyz ";
    CLLocationCoordinate2D crd2;
    crd2.latitude = ;
    crd2.longitude = ;
    [aPlace2 addCoordinates:crd2];
    [places addObject:aPlace2];
    [aPlace2 release];
    aPlace2 = nil;

}


-(void) initializeNavigationalBar {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centreCarte;
    centreCarte.latitude = ;
    centreCarte.longitude = ;
    MKCoordinateSpan zoom;

    zoom.latitudeDelta = 2;
    zoom.longitudeDelta = zoom.latitudeDelta;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = centreCarte;
    region.span = zoom; 

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView addAnnotations:places];
}
```

Comment: Plz check i update my code ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't show the "Google logo", your app will be rejected.
The default logo is shown in southwest position in the map.

Use this:

```
- (UIImageView*) googleLogo {

    UIImageView *imgView = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            imgView = (UIImageView*)subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    return imgView;
}

@end
```

to change the google logo position this is the snippet:

```
- (void) alignGoogleLogo:(UITextAlignment) alignment {

  UIImageView *logo = [self googleLogo];
  CGRect frame = logo.frame;
  float padding = 9;

  if (alignment == UITextAlignmentLeft) {

    frame.origin.x = padding;

  } else if (alignment == UITextAlignmentCenter) {

    frame.origin.x = (self.size.width / 2) - (frame.size.width / 2);

  } else if (alignment == UITextAlignmentRight) {

    frame.origin.x = self.size.width - frame.size.width - padding;
  }

  [logo setFrame:frame];

}
```